# apixu.client.ApixuException: Error code 1003: "Parameter q is missing."

Tags: python, bots, chatbot, rasa-nlu

I do not understand the error I got this time, I'm running the apixu.com API on rasa_core when running even issued this kind of error, can you help me to explain it?

> ERROR:rasa_core.processor:Encountered an exception while running action 'action_weather'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Make sure to fix the exception in your custom code.
>
> ERROR:rasa_core.processor:Error code 1003: "Parameter q is missing."
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\processor.py", line 302, in _run_action
>     events = action.run(dispatcher, tracker, self.domain)
>
>  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\actions.py", line 18, in run
>     current = client.getCurrentWeather(q=loc)
>  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apixu\client.py", line 37, in getCurrentWeather
>     return self._get(url, args)
>
>  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\apixu\client.py", line 27, in _get
>     raise ApixuException(message=err_msg, code=err_code)
>
> apixu.client.ApixuException: Error code 1003: "Parameter q is missing."
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have q as a parameter in the url. apixu alovs you to find the weather of a city using lontitude and latitude, city name, ZIP codes, and so on. but no matter what you use, you have to have q in the url. in the link below, you can see how you can use the parameter q.

https://www.apixu.com/doc/request.aspx